# Image of rational numbers under the polynomial map

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

I have the following problem:

> **Problem.** For polynomials $f$ and $g$ with rational coefficients prove that $f(\mathbb{Q})=g(\mathbb{Q})$ iff $f(x)=g(ax+b)$ for some rational numbers $a, b$ with $a\neq 0$.

It's clear that if $\ell(x)=ax+b$ where $a\in\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $\ell(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$, so if $f(x)=g(ax+b)$ then $f(\mathbb{Q})=g(\mathbb{Q})$.

However, the converse is not so obvious. My idea was to prove first the statement when leading coefficents of both polynomials are positive, i. e.
$$
f=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0,~g=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots+m_0
$$
and $a_n,b_m>0$. If degrees of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are odd, then there exists $A,M>0$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are increasing functions on $[A,+\infty)$ and for all $y_0>M$ there exists unique $x_1=x_1(y)$ and unique $x_2=x_2(y)$ such that $f(x_1)=g(x_2)=y$. Moreover, if we consider $x_1$ and $x_2$ as functions of variable $y$, then
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}x_1(y)=+\infty,
\\
\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}x_2(y)=+\infty.
$$
Since $f(t)\sim a_nt^{n}$ and $g(t)\sim b_mt^{m}$ when $t\rightarrow +\infty$ we obtain that
$$
1=\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{y}{y}=\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x_1(y))}{g(x_2(y))}=\lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_n(x_1(y))^{n}}{b_m(x_2(y))^{m}}.
$$
Hence, $a_n(x_1(y))^{n}\sim b_m(x_2(y))^{m}$ when $y$ tends to infinity. If we prove that $x_1(y)=ax_2(y)+b$ for some $a$ and $b$, then the equality $f(x)=g(ax+b)$ holds for infinitely many distinct real $x$, so $f(x)\equiv g(ax+b)$. However, I don't how even to prove that $n=m$.

So, is there any way to continue this approach?

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269855/polynomials-with-same-image-on-the-rationals

Comment: Yes, thanks, I see. However, there isn't any answer to this question.

Comment: Here: https://www.docdroid.net/vyGkcyK/solution.pdf

Comment: It would be great if you could type it as an answer to the other question.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it. I'm just curious: where did you find ths problem (i. e. the name of the book)?

Comment: [The book](https://www.amazon.com/Contests-Higher-Mathematics-Schweitzer-Competitions/dp/0387945881)